# How can I donate money to the Canadian federal government?

Tags: canada, charity, donation, government, charitable-contributions

Lots of governments accept donations from members of the public. For example, I know the government of Ontario accepts donations through the [Ontario Opportunities Fund](http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/credit/oof/index.html). I also know that the US federal government accepts donations, even [by credit card](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/resources/faq/faq_publicdebt.htm#DebtFinance).

But how can I make a charitable donation to the Government of Canada? [(Not that I should.)](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/5045/5496)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about that, Thanks!

Comment: @littleadv: You're welcome. But -- you actually want to donate money to your government? Why?

Comment: Oh, I think I donate enough. More than enough in fact:) But its still cool to know that an option exist, IIRC we actually had a question about it here a while ago and no-one knew this answer.

Comment: @littleadv: Was the question specifically about donating money to the Canadian federal government? Also, if you can find it, mind to please provide a link?

Comment: It was to the US government, I'll look it up later.

Comment: If you want to help your government without simply giving money away [and I can think of many more deserving charities...], consider buying local bonds, or, dare I say it on a finance forum, buying lottery tickets that fund specific government programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [relevant page](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/tax-packages-years/general-income-tax-benefit-package/5000-g/general-income-tax-benefit-guide-federal-tax-credits-schedule-1.html#P1447_193618) of the [CRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_Revenue_Agency)'s 2016 General Income Tax and Benefit Guide explains how to donate money to the federal debt servicing and reduction account. The guide writes:

> To make a gift to this account, make it payable to the Receiver General, and send it with a note asking that we apply it to this account, to:
>
> Place du Portage
>   Phase III, 11 Laurier Street
>   Gatineau, Quebec
>   K1A 0S5

Donations are tax-deductible: they'll send you a tax receipt.